# Administration and website url not not reachable a after system reboot

Tags: kentico

I am trying to learn kentico so i install kentico in my laptop. when I install it, it is working fine like MedioClinic, Dancing Goat example. But when I restart my system the below link no longer reachable. If I uninstall and install then it works again. Is there any service need to run after reboot system?

http://localhost:56624/Kentico12_1_Admin/

http://localhost:56624/Kentico12_1_DancingGoatMvc

I am a new to Kentico. Please help me to understand.

Best regards,
Shekhar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely what is happening is the port number is being reassigned so those instances are not running.  OR it's dependent on a Visual Studio instance to be running with starts IIS Express in the background.

My suggestion would be to register them in your local version of IIS to avoid any complications you might run into with Visual Studio and IIS Express.

Comment: Thank you - Brenden for give me this Idea. I was in a under impression that might be some short of service, automatic run those particular port without running my VS like when I install initially(I guess, VS instance run automatically at that time). So when system reboot, I was searching any Kentico services stop or not. That was my mistake.  Now I run through my VS setting this particular port . It works! - Thank you.